# Formal evidence for statement involving matrices A and AB times vector x = c

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

True or false?

If for every $\mathbf{c} \in F^n$ there is a solution to the system $AB\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{c}$, then for every **c** $\in F^n$ there is a solution to the system $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{c}$. I intuitively understand that this is correct, but I am wondering if there is a formal way to prove it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: this solution is only applicable for square matrices. See Sean Lee's counter-example with non-square matrices above.

For a matrix $D$, the existence of a solution to $Dx=c$ for all $c\in F^n$ is equivalent to invertibility of $D$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979299/prove-that-if-ax-b-has-a-solution-for-every-b-then-a-is-invertible) - this is actually only one direction but it is the one we want). In particular, here we get that $AB$ is invertible and by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459021/prove-that-if-ab-is-invertible-then-b-is-invertible), $B$ is invertible (and so is $A$).

Comment: This assumes that $A$ and $B$ are square. There is no such assumption in the question, however.

Comment: @SeanLee Right. I missed that. Your solution indeed clears things up, then.

Answer (score 1):

Its not correct.

Take

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 0 \\
    0      & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 \\
    0      & 1 \\
    0      & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then

$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 \\
    0      & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus there will be a solution for the system $AB\bf{x} = \bf{c}, \ \forall \bf{c} \in F^n$ (the solution is just $ \bf{x} = \bf{c}$), however there will not necessarily be a solution for $B \bf{x} = \bf{c}$. For example, there is no solution for the following system:
$$
B\bf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 \\
    0      & 1 \\
    0      & 0
\end{bmatrix} \bf{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}
$$